# How to find children in a tree of xml?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I just realized that the `findall` method in python's xml module only searches through the direct children of the element on which it is called, and doesn't look into all subelements.

What if I want to just find all instances of an `<arbitrary>` tag inside an xml tree, nested to any depth? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iterparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename, events=('end', )):
    if elem.tag == 'arbitrary':
        ...
```

---

If you have [lxml](http://lxml.de/) installed, you could use [iterparse](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk) (note the `tag` parameter):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(filename, events=('end', ), tag='arbitrary'):
    ...
```

or using XPath:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
for elem in tree.xpath('//arbitrary'):
    ...
```